# vCards compatible with all smartphones

Tags: web, smartphone, vcf-vcard

I have a website where the user can download a vCard for each represented contact.

Works great on desktop, but does not work on (all) smartphones.

Is there any way to make a vCard compatible to all major smartphone operating systems?

Thanks in advance.

Best, Mario

Comment: Can you post an example of one of the vCards?  There may be an error somewhere that is preventing it from being parsed by all systems.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the vCard may have an impact on its cross-platform compatibility.  Try encoding the vCard as version 2.1.  This is the oldest version, so it's likely to be the most broadly compatibile.